# How to check whether a port is opened on server or not?

Tags: ssh, php, port, websocket

I have been using Shared hosting to host my website. I want to deploy a PHP WebSocket application built using Ratchet PHP. So I want it to listen on port 9000.

When I ran command `php server.php` in my SSH access it shows server is started and listening on domain.com:9000. But in my chat application, It takes some time and then says:

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at
>   ws://domain.com:9000/

Also, I have checked `telnet domain.com 9000` which results in

> Could not open connection to the host, on port 9000: Connect failed.

I contacted the support about it, they says

> Your Port 9000 is opened for OutBound Connections.

How can I check whether my port is opened? and also If opened why It doesn't listens to the connections made by a web browser as client to server?

Answer (score 3):

> Your Port 9000 is opened for OutBound Connections.

But that's not what you're trying to do. You're trying to make an **inbound** connection to the server, not an outbound connection from the server.

> How can I check whether my port is opened?

Contact the hosting provider, and be clear that you want to set up a *listener* on port 9000 on your shared-hosting account, rather than making outbound connections.

On a shared server, the hosting provider might not allow any inbound connections at all, or they might require you to use a specific range of ports.

(Meanwhile, on a private/dedicated server, the only restrictions are those that you've set yourself on the server's firewall, so you would check by looking at the firewall rules – iptables, ufw, firewalld, and such.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access, in a linux system, you can query your firewall rules using iptables:

```bsh
sudo iptables -S | grep ACCEPT
```

If the firewall rule's was modified using the `firewall-cmd`, you can query the rules using the following command:

```bsh
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

For a complete 'map' of the firewall (useful if you need to understand how the various chain are configured), you can run the following command:

```bsh
sudo iptables -L
```

Comment: iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

Comment: These command have to be sent using the super user. Login as root or place 'sudo' before the command in order to run it as superuser

Answer (score 0):

Here is my bash script to check the Open ports!

```
log_file=log_file    
ip_list=("192.168.111.1" "192.168.111.2" "192.168.111.3")    
#ip_list=$(cat ip_addr.txt)  #put all ip in the text file 
        for ip in "${ip_list[@]}"
             do
              nc -z -w5 "$ip" 22
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    echo "$ip port 22 is open " >> $log_file
                else
                    echo "SSH port 22 is not open on $ip"
                fi
            done
```

To check the port is open or not use `nc`  for check the port.